# Sometimes throws Bad file descriptor error, sometimes doesn't

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell, process

The following piece of code was working fine for a year, of late it intermittently started failing with following error, wonder if any OS or hardware change is causing this

```
import subprocess
def bash_command(cmd):
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
    process.wait()

bash_command("bash myscript.sh")
```

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/p2/shell_way/all_in_one_refill.py",
line 68,
    bash myscript.sh   File "/Users/ishandutta2007/Documents/Projects/p2/shell_way/all_in_one_refill.py",
line 31, in bash_command
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")   File
"/Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py",
line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)   File "/Users/ishandutta2007/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py",
line 1326, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg) OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Python provides lengthy, detailed, and very information error messages.  Your question only includes a short excerpt from it.  Can show us the complete error message and stack trace?

Comment: @John1024 updated the question

Comment: Perhaps try `bash_command("myscript.sh")`? If you're calling `Popen` with `shell=True`, you shouldn't need to specify `bash` as part of the command.

Comment: @A.L.Flanagan It depends.  There are systems, such as Debian and Ubuntu, for which the default shell, `/bin/sh`, is chosen to be a fast POSIX shell, _not__ `bash`.  If `cmd` requires bash features, then it is important to specify `executable="/bin/bash"`.

Comment: @ishandutta2007 Very good.  Unfortunately, I believe that that error message just says that we need more information.  Apparently, `cmd` is attempting to access a closed file.  It might, for example, be one of the standard files, stdin, stdout, and stderr, which `cmd` is trying to use but has been closed in the python program using, for example, `os.close()`.

Comment: My concerns are around memory leak or similar kind of things. This script used to work fine when data was less it used to complete in 5 mins, now data is more, takes more than 30 mins, and hence occasionally fails with this error.

Comment: or else upgrades to the system or change in python packages in the environment might be impacting. As far as python version is concerned we are consistent with 3.6 throughout